# Как импортировать материал в базу данных, который содержит php-скрипт?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, импорт

Как импортировать таблицу с материалами сайта в базу данных, которые содержат php-скрипт?
При импорте возникает ошибка:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near '. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']' at line
> 2

Как насильно импортировать в БД данную таблицу?

Запрос:

```
> INSERT INTO `esr_content` (`id`, `asset_id`, `title`, `alias`,
> `introtext`, `fulltext`, `state`, `catid`, `created`, `created_by`,
> `created_by_alias`, `modified`, `modified_by`, `checked_out`,
> `checked_out_time`, `publish_up`, `publish_down`, `images`, `urls`,
> `attribs`, `version`, `ordering`, `metakey`, `metadesc`, `access`,
> `hits`, `metadata`, `featured`, `language`, `xreference`, `note`)
> VALUES (79, 224, 'Главная', 'home', '\r\n <div class="container">\r\n
> <div class="akcii-main">\r\n <div class="col-md-6 akcii-div-1">\r\n
> <h3 class="akcii-h3">Акции сервисного центра</h3>\r\n <p
> class="akcii-p">Скидки и бонусы от центра по предварительной записи на
> ремонт</p>\r\n </div>\r\n <div class="col-md-6 akcii-div-2">\r\n <a
> href="javascript:void(0);" class="akcii-a qf3modal" data-project="3"
> data-url="{source}[[?php\r\n$url = ((!empty($_SERVER[\'HTTPS\'])) ?
> \'https\' : \'http\') . \':/\/' . $_SERVER[\'HTTP_HOST\'] .
> $_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\']
```

Comment: Добавьте строку где возникает ошибка

Comment: И что ты посоветушь? Экранировать кавычки? Не проще сразу про prepared statements рассказать?

Comment: @u_mulder я бы вообще заменил всё $_SERVER параметры на константы и использовал реплейс какой-то при выгрузке. А, вообще, незачем html в базе держать